# How to Select a div that has attribute equals to

Tags: jquery

I have trouble selecting a div's html content by selecting the div based on its attribute value.

My html is this:

```
<div id="infowrap1" class="widgetInfobox" possition="1" wid="QI" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap2" class="widgetInfobox" possition="2" wid="CP" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap3" class="widgetInfobox" possition="3" wid="PP" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap4" class="widgetInfobox" possition="4" wid="MT" style="">.....</div>
```

Lets say I want to get the html() of div with possition=1 ...
I tried using

```
var p1=$(".widgetInfobox [possition='1']").html();
alert(p1);
```

..but I get 'undefined', where if I alert only `$(".widgetInfobox [possition='1']")` I get `[object Object]`. If I select the `.text()` I get empty string.

How can I do this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use non-standard attributes (and correct your spelling) :). Use `data-position` instead for HTML compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's sizzle selector engine follows CSS rules. As such, to select an element using multiple clauses you should not add spaces between them. Try this:

```
var p1 = $(".widgetInfobox[possition='1']").html();
```

It should also be noted that `possition` and `wid` are not a standard attributes of a `div` element. Using it will mean that your HTML is invalid. You should instead use `data-*` attributes:

```
<div id="infowrap1" class="widgetInfobox" data-position="1" data-wid="QI" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap2" class="widgetInfobox" data-position="2" data-wid="CP" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap3" class="widgetInfobox" data-position="3" data-wid="PP" style="">.....</div>
<div id="infowrap4" class="widgetInfobox" data-position="4" data-wid="MT" style="">.....</div>
```

```js
var p1 = $(".widgetInfobox[data-position='1']").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between class and attribute selector, as space will make it descendant selector which will find elements with attribute possition='1' within descendant of `.widgetInfobox`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/384hkvg2/)

```
var p1=$(".widgetInfobox[possition='1']").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's not a descendant selector** Just Remove the space between the class and attribute.

```
var p1=$(".widgetInfobox[possition='1']").html();
```

I think id be unique in your code Let's take with id easily

```
var p1 = $("#infowrap1").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

remove space between class and attribute otherwise it will select child element of `.widgetInfobox` which has attribute `possition='1'`:-

```
var p1=$(".widgetInfobox[possition='1']").html();
alert(p1);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8y3ebqq/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/duyba3fg/)

```
var p1=$("[possition='1']").html();
alert(p1);
```

OR

```
var p1=$("div[possition='1']").html();
alert(p1);
```

NOTE : you can use standers attribute name `data-possition` instead of  `possition`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/duyba3fg/2/)